# Android UI without using classic android UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm starting to learn android development and i learned that to make a GUI you can use the "android classic UI" (button, textfield...etc).

I was wondering how was the angry birds (or any other "nice looking" UI) UI was done. I guess they didn't used the "classic android UI"

I just want to know what do they use?

I know a lot of you will get mad at me for asking this kind of question. Sorry but it's a question that i have in mind for a long time now.

Thank you!

Comment: You can also use things like borderless buttons (1 xml change) and custom views (can get quite complicated). I would think the look of Android has significantly improved since 4.0 developer UI guidelines were posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best performance, usually games are developed in OpenGL ES. the latest version is OpenGL ES 3.0. You can try some sample code from Android SDK.

Comment: Ok, i get it for the games, but is it the same thing for apps like the google play store app? thank you!

Comment: It depends. Someone likes to use OpenGL, some just wants to use View. The graphics subsystem consists of Skia & OpenGL(Software & Hardware). I suggest you reading [this article](http://withimagination.imgtec.com/index.php/news/learning-about-the-android-graphics-subsystem).

Answer (score 1):

Angry Birds and games like that use OpenGL ES

Comment: Ok, i get it for the games, but is it the same thing for apps like the google play store app? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it's different between app and game develop,app use the basic UI(sometimes we have to write ui self) game usualy use engine to make app.